# Data binding and observables in Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-observables

Let me first say that I'm new in Angular 2.

So I'm creating a service which gets a variable from a response header.
This is the code:

```
export class MyService{
constructor (private http: Http) {}

public doThings(varA:string, varB:string){
  let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
  let options = new RequestOptions();
  let data={
    foo:{
      thing1: varA,
      thing2: varB
    }
  };
  let body = JSON.stringify(data,null,2);
  this.http.post("http://localhost:4000/foo", body , options)
    .map((res)=> res.headers.get("foo"))
    .subscribe((data)=> this.myValue = data);
}
public myValue = "";
}
```

the Component A calls the doThings function which populate myValue:

```
...

export class AComponent {
  constructor(private mySvc:MyService){}
  vara;
  varb;
  onClick(){
    this.mySvc.doThings(this.vara,this.varb);
  }
}
```

The App component watch the myValue value in order to hide/show certain things in the template

```
...
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private mySvc: MyService){}
  val = this.mySvc.myValue;
}
```

The issue is that in the AppComponent `val` is always set to "" even after the component b calls `doThings`

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: `val = this.mySvc.myValue;` is just a one-time action. When this line is executed the response from the server hasn't yet arrived. When it then arrives eventually, this line won't update `val` anymore. You need to properly chain async calls. There about 200 similar questions here already.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer mmm ok thanks now it's clearer, but I'm still not able to figure out how it should be done.

Comment: Use `map` instead of `subscribe` and pass the `Observable` you get from `http.get(...)` along. Where you need the result use `theObservable.subscribe(val => { /* do something with the value*/})`

Comment: Check one of the Observable tutorials like https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/01/06/taking-advantage-of-observables-in-angular2.html, https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/observables/using_observables.html, http://blog.angular-university.io/how-to-build-angular2-apps-using-rxjs-observable-data-services-pitfalls-to-avoid/, ...